# Immutable list in .NET: Why are you allowed to add and remove items?

Tags: java, c#, list, immutability

In C#, I just got the need of having an **immutable list, meaning that the list can not be changed**.

Much like in Java's immutable list: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/immutable-list-in-java/

From there:

> If any attempt is made to add null element in List,
>   UnsupportedOperationException is thrown.

Now, with .NET (at least with Core 2.2) there is also an immutable list, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=netcore-2.2).

They say (emphasis mine):

> When you add or remove items from an immutable list, a copy of the
>   original list is made with the **items added or removed**, and the
>   original list is unchanged.

So, this implementation basically allows changing the list (by getting a manipulated copy each time), as opposed to the java understanding, and what's more, it will mostly go undetected clogging memory.

**What's the point in having an immutable list that supports add and remove methods in the first place?**

The problem for me here is, that users of my code would get a list, immutable presumably, but out of neglectance would happily add items, which will never made it to the original "repository". This will cause confusion.

**I guess the (only) way to go here, to forbid manipulation entirely, and make it clear to the code user, would be to use the IEnumerale interface?**

Comment: The immutable aspect applies the instance itself, not the data the instance contains, so of course you can read the data out of the list and add a new element and create a new immutable list from that.

Comment: IEnumerable allow you to do things like this:
`myIEnumerableCollection.Union(new[]{newItem}).ToList()`
This will still create a new object and not modify the original one. Immutability is a property of an instance. If you chose to throw or copy when modifying it, both are valid approaches that don't violate the immutability aspect of an instance

Comment: @disklosr Good point. I'll likely end up using the IEnumerable, because that's what I am concerned most: Providing a set, and at the same time communicating, that a user can't add a thing to the original set. This way, it's up to them creating a copy if they should need so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the point in having an immutable list that supports add and
>   remove methods in the first place?

No one but to be conform with the `List` contract, the implementation even immutable will expose every `List` methods.
After you have two ways to cope with these modification methods : throwing an exception or guaranteeing the immutability by creating and returning a new List at each modification.

About :

> I guess the (only) way to go here, to forbid manipulation entirely,
>   would be to use the IEnumerale interface?

Indeed, in Java you use `Iterable` (that is close enough) when you want to be able to manipulate a collection of things without a way to change it.
As alternative you can also use an array.

Comment: "...even immutable will expose every List methods" pretty much nails the "Why" part.

Comment: I'm being picky here but if immutability is so important in your system, you should use true immutable collection implementations. Using IEnumerable or the better alternative (imo) IReadOnlyCollection only hides the problem as nothing is stopping you from casting back to the original type and mutating it.

Comment: @disklosr I agree completely and to go further I think that in most of cases, immutability matters because it makes your system more robust. Just much people don't be used to use it, so don't use it...  In C# do you have true immutable classes  (standard  or third party library) ?

Answer (score 1):

As you said: "*a copy of the original list is made with the items added or removed, and the original list is unchanged.*".

So you can add/remove elements and a new list is made with the changes. The original list is unchanged.

Comment: Yes, we read that, but why the list isn't created from the constructor, and the constructor only?

Comment: @Phillip take a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=netcore-2.2#remarks

Answer (score 1):

> What's the point in having an immutable list that supports add and remove methods in the first place?

First think of this: What is the point of an immutable list that *doesn't* support adding or removing items in any way? There is nothing particular useful to that. You can use array for that.

Now back to your question. The list is immutable, so consumers can't change the instance itself which was provided through some other method or class. The backing storage can't be altered by consumers! But the producer of the immutable list can 'alter' the backing store by creating a new immutable list and assigning that to the original variable. Isn't that useful!

Comment: Regarding your first point, an Array is mutable (unless it's empty) so it's not a replacement of an immutable list.

Comment: You can only expand an array by creating a new one, right? @disklosr Or did I miss anything crucial here?

Comment: You cannot expand an array but you can replace elements inside it, which makes it mutable. Here's an interesting read about this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful/

Comment: Ah yes. Of course. The comparison doesn't go up entirely.